# How to get multiple key values from array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have below object in javascript:

```
var users = [{
    'user': 'barney',
    'age': 36,
    'active': true
}, {
    'user': 'fred',
    'age': 40,
    'active': false
}, {
    'user': 'pebbles',
    'age': 1,
    'active': true
}];
```

I want to get a new object from above object but remove `active` key like below:

```
var users = [{
        'user': 'barney',
        'age': 36,
    }, {
        'user': 'fred',
        'age': 40,
    }, {
        'user': 'pebbles',
        'age': 1,
    }];
```

I know that I can create the object by a for-loop, but I am looking for a better way to do that. Whether it can be done by one line of lodash code?

Comment: Why do you favor a library solution over a  loop?

Comment: [`_.map(users, user => _.omit(user, 'active'))`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bduh1b50/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a library.

```
var result = users.map(el => {
   delete el.active;
   return el;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can use the latest JavaScript features...

```
users = users.map(({ active, ...rest }) => rest);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/22kqjvc5/1/

Comment: 1+ - Nice! That is a really clever usage of the spread operator.

Answer (score 4):

### An ES6 way to do this

```js
var users = [{
    'user': 'barney',
    'age': 36,
    'active': true
  }, {
    'user': 'pebbles',
    'age': 1,
    'active': true
}];

console.log ( _.map(users, i => _.pick(i, 'user', 'active'))  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

[Inspired by this](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1247)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) in combination with [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) in order to omit the `active` property:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4vg6hhvq/)

```
_.map(users, user => _.omit(user, 'active'))
```